# phpdesktop-chrome - Not Working for Header in php

Tags: php, phpdesktop

I have a PHP file and whenever running a file in PHP **phpdesktop-chrome (APP)** I am getting below and I have only the following code in my file.

```
header("Content-Type: application/xls");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

Following is my error code.

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Program Files\abc\www\backend\check.php:2)
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Program Files\abc\www\backend\check.php:3)
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Program Files\abc\www\backend\check.php:4)
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Program Files\abc\www\backend\check.php:5)
```

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/8028957/9354303

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert `ob_start();` after the first `<?php` opening tag.

Comment: getting the same warning.